# Android Mirror - JUC600 for Ubuntu

Tags: android

I was recently reading an article about a device that mirrors an Android device onto a computer. Once connected you can then interact with it via the computers keyboard as well as amplify the screen.

***This leads to my actual question has anyone seen a similar project that will run on Ubuntu?***

**Key Features**

1. Display your phone on your PC
2. Magnify & Rotate your phone's screen on your large display
3. Copy and Paste text from your PC to your phone or vice versa
4. Use your keyboard and mouse to directly type or click any programs
5. Transfer data through the file manager
6. Get incoming call and text message notifications directly on your PC
7. Take quick and easy screenshots of your phone

**References**

[Android Mirror Website](http://www.j5create.com/our-products/android/juc600.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android).

Comment: I think that's a great project but the main reason I'm asking is that I would like to interact with some of my Android database apps on the big screen with a normal keyboard. I have a triple boot netbook with Ubuntu/Android/Windows but I have to sync my changes back to the phone and I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a VNC server on the device and then using a remote-desktop application (Remmina, or other) on Ubuntu to connect to the phone. That should provide everything you're asking for.

You'll need root on your Android device. There are dozens of the server apps available (they're probably the same open-source software repackaged) but here you go:

- https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vnc+server&c=apps

Comment: That's a very interesting approach my phone is rooted so I will give it a go. Thanks

Comment: I personally find it very sluggish :(

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen If it's a slow device with a relatively fast network, consider turning the compression down. If it's a faster device, turn the compression up.

Comment: Yes, I did play with the settings, still found it s...l...u...g...i...s...h if you catch my meaning.